# Visual Basic 6 :: Unload Dynamically Created Form

Tags: forms, timer, vb6, sleep

I'm trying hard to solve that issue without any luck :(

Here is my code :

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private frm As Form

Public Sub GenerateForm()

    Set frm = New myForm

    With frm
        .Width = 4000
        .Height = 3000
        .Caption = "Message"
    End With

    frm.Move (Screen.Width - Me.Width) / 2, (Screen.Height - Me.Height) / 2

    frm.Show vbModal

    Sleep 3000

    Unload Me
    Set frm = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    GenerateForm

End Sub
```

I want to close the newly created form automatically after 3 seconds.

Comment: Do you really mean `Unload Me`, or do you mean `Unload frm`?

Comment: Your design is BAD practice. You shouldn't show a message to a user and then remove it a few seconds later as it only confuses the user and they will assume something has gone wrong. Change the design and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 2):

Windows opened in modal mode wait for user input, so the statements after

```
frm.Show vbModal
```

will not execute.

.

You have two solutions:

a) remove vbModal

b) add Timer on **myForm** and set Interval to 1000 (mean 1 second), next add this code in Timer event:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Static sec As Integer
    sec = sec + 1
    If sec >= 3 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Last, you should use

```
Unload frm
```

since Unload Me is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the timer like this, once it reaches 3 seconds (3000) it will close the form and open another one.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    If Timer1.Interval = 3000 Then
        frm_Menu.Show
        Unload frmSplash
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```