# VISUAL BASIC 6 :: Unload Splash Form With Timer

Tags: forms, function, timer, vb6, basic

My code is working properly up until the point when I want to unload the newly generated form.

I have 2 timers :: 1 for load the splash form and 1 for unload the splash form.

```
Option Explicit

Private frmSplash As Form

Private Sub splashForm()

    Set frmSplash = New myForm

    With frmSplash
        .Width = 4000
        .Height = 3000
        .Caption = "Splash"
    End With

    frmSplash.Show vbModal

    unloadSplash.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()

    Me.Move (Screen.Width - Me.Width) / 2, (Screen.Height - Me.Height) / 2
    splashTimer.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub splashTimer_Timer()

   splashForm

End Sub

Private Sub unloadSplash_Timer()

    'MsgBox "Am I alive ?"

    Unload frmSplash
    Set frmSplash = Nothing

    unloadSplash.Enabled = False
    splashTimer.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Seems like `unloadSplash_Timer` is not enabled after `splashTimer.Enabled = True`...

Comment: See solutions #2 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565625/visual-basic-6-unload-dynamically-created-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic 6 :: Unload Dynamically Created Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565625/visual-basic-6-unload-dynamically-created-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "vbModal" stop your code in that command. You must to move the timer of unload splash form in to the splash form.

The events order is this:

```
-> sub Form_Activate
-> sub splashTimer_Timer
-> sub splashForm
---> frmSplash.Show vbModal (here the code stop until your form is not unload)
     /* If you close manualy the "frmSplash" the the timer "unloadSplash" start. */
```

Comment: @GoPro It's a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move your timer in your splash form and execute it from there and only have single time if you wish. So in a nut shell:

- Application starts > Splash screen shown
- Splash screen on load > Timer starts (specified interval - Tick)
- Timer Tick event > Close the Splash screen > Load main form.